# How to use MMA to make these triangles into a Pentagon according to the equal length side?

Tags: graphics, geometry

I tried to use `Polygon` but failed.

```
Graphics[{Red, SSSTriangle[541, 26, 525]}]
Graphics[{Yellow, SSSTriangle[525, 91, 476]}]
Graphics[{Blue, SSSTriangle[476, 195, 421]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Were you expecting a picture like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtoRK.png)?

Comment: What might your pentagon look like? [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzY78.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxzzo.png) look like quadrilaterals to me.

Comment: They aren't pentagons, as I said.Perhaps seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3sSl.png) might help you see why.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, but how to get these splices? @J.M.